# How to Save file to Downloads folder on Android >=33

Tags: android, flutter

I've a flutter app with audio files downloaded from network. I want to download an audio file to my devices Downloads folder to make it usable for later use like Making it a Ringtone or similar.

Previously I used WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission via [permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package's Permission.storage.

From their doc,

> As of Android SDK 30 (Android 11) the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is considered a high-risk or sensitive permission. There for it is required to declare the use of these permissions if you intend to release the application via the Google Play Store.

So, to save file on Downloads folder, I need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (via Permissions. manageExternalStorage). But when I add this permission and submit my app, the update is rejected via google saying that this is not a core functionality of my add and I should use less risky APIs to access data.

So, if I target API 33 or above, how can I download an audio file to my Android devices Downloads folder?

Comment: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161679/android-crud-mediastore-api-26/68361660#68361660) might be helpful

Comment: You can download as before. You did not even tell wich problems you have to do so.

Comment: `So, to save file on Downloads folder, I need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` That is just not true.

Comment: @anatoli I'm seeking flutter only solution

Comment: @blackapps So, please add an answer how to do it. I can't find a solution, that's why posted it.

Comment: Just use the code you always used. That was what i suggested.

Comment: @blackapps "On Android the Permission.storage permission is linked to the Android READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Starting from Android SDK 29 (Android 10) the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions have been marked deprecated and have been fully removed/ disabled since Android SDK 33 (Android 13)." https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#faq

Comment: I dont understand why you without any comment dump and repeat what you said before. I did not suggest to use those permissions for Android 13+ devices.

Comment: @blackapps if you spent few seconds reading both you would have understood both are not same and reading these are important to understand the scenario, that’s why posted

Comment: @blackapps as I mentioned early, when I tried, in API<33, everything works like before, but for API>=33, I'm needing special permission to save a file, which works, but it rejected by google console as that permission is now considered "high risk" by google

Comment: Repeat. You do not need a special permission. You can just save your file. It's time you do.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, on Android>=33, to write file on external storage, you will not need any permissions at all!

> More recent versions of Android rely more on a file's purpose than its
> location for determining an app's ability to access, and write to, a
> given file. In particular, if your app targets Android 11 (API level
> 30) or higher, the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission doesn't have any
> effect on your app's access to storage. This purpose-based storage
> model improves user privacy because apps are given access only to the
> areas of the device's file system that they actually use.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation and found a solution that might be helpful. Instead of relying on the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, I chose to directly assign the path '/storage/emulated/0/Download' to save the files.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

static Future saveFile(String fileName, List<int> bytes) async {
    Directory? directory;
    File? file;
    try {
      if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
        //downloads folder - android only - API>30
        directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      } else {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      }

      bool hasExisted = await directory.exists();
      if (!hasExisted) {
        directory.create();
      }

      //file to saved
      file = File("${directory.path}${Platform.pathSeparator}$fileName.pdf");
      if (!file.existsSync()) {
        await file.create();
      }
      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    } catch (e) {
      if (file != null && file.existsSync()) {
        file.deleteSync();
      }
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

This solution worked for me; I hope it proves useful in solving your issue as well.

Comment: Hi @lunna-lm, how about lower API (API<30)?

Answer (score 1):

**Android**: The following code works for Android 11 and above (API level 30+)

As per *Google Play store* new policy there is no need to get/request any permission to `write or read` files from storage. **This is applicable only for (your) App owned directory such as: Cache, Temporary, External, Document, Download directories etc.**

But to get access of this directory `/storage/emulated/0/Download` or at this level, you must get permission using *permission_handler* like as `Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()`
and must declare permission in Android Manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="34"/>`.

If your app using `Permission.manageExternalStorage.request()` such then while uploading to PlayStore you must submit details and reason to use such **high level permission**. You can read more about this `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final String imageUrl =
      'https://satsang-foundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Ganesha-Chathurthi-TSF-4.jpg';
  final Dio dio = Dio();
  double progress = 0.0;
  bool loading = false;

  Future<bool> saveFile(String url) async {
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        Directory? directory;
        directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
        String path = '${directory!.path}/Shri Ganesha.jpeg';
        File savePath = File(path);
        await dio.download(
          url,
          savePath.path,
          onReceiveProgress: (downloadedSize, totalSize) {
            setState(() {
              progress = downloadedSize / totalSize;
            });
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return false;
  }

  void downloadImage() async {
    bool download = await saveFile(imageUrl);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Image.network(
                  imageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
              LinearProgressIndicator(
                minHeight: 10.0,
                value: progress,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: downloadImage,
                child: const Text('Download'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```